# Does the new Nexus 7 (2013) have a GLONASS sensor?

Tags: nexus-7, gps, glonass

According to a colleague who has the new Nexus 7 (2013) model already, there is a [GLONASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLONASS) sensor in addition to the GPS one in the device. Is this true? I was unable to find any reference to this alleged fact in the official documentation and via a casual web search.

Please state your sources in your answer(s).

Comment: Seems to me it should be your colleague providing the proof for his allegation.

Comment: @AlEverett: he just did. We work in different time zones. He says there are 21 sats available (which the existing accepted answer shows means GLONASS) and the GLONASS sats are marked differently in the GPS diagnostic app he uses.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a screenshot of the GPS diagnostic app displaying glonass satellites?

Comment: @Flow: followed up on your request by putting up my own answer. But the accepted one will be kept the way it is, since it was very helpful in finding out the details I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Ifixit's teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nexus+7+2nd+Generation+Teardown/16072/2), the Nexus 7 2013 uses the Qualcomm 8064 Snapdragon S4 Pro SoC.  [Qualcomm's specs](http://www.qualcomm.com/snapdragon/processors/s4/specs) show that SoC uses their IZat Gen8A GNSS chipset, which according to [their overview](https://www.qca.qualcomm.com/technology/brand.php?brand=9&product=117) does include GLONASS support, though this doesn't necessarily mean GLONASS support is actually active and available in software.

A simple means to test whether you've got GLONASS is to use [GPS Status and Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) and see how many satellites it shows for you.  If it shows more than 13 satellites, you're getting both GPS and GLONASS.

Comment: very useful answer. Shows 21 sats, and the GLONASS ones differently marked than the GPS ones according to my colleague. So together with your answer I conclude that GLONASS is available at least in the US models of the Nexus 7 (2013).

Comment: I'll add to the above that the Nexus 7 is very fast in geolocating the user, even though it has no cellphone support so must rely entirely on GPS + Glonass.

Answer (score 5):

The definite answer is yes. I received my Nexus 7 (2013) a few weeks ago and today went outside to catch a few satellites. I'm using *GPS Status & Toolbox* whose user guide states:

> The sky grid (G) shows the GPS satellites above you as the receiver in
>   the phone detects them. GPS satellites (with IDs 1-32) are represented
>   by small circles **while GLONASS satellites (with IDs 65-92) are shown
>   as rectangles**. The size of the symbol depends on the signal strength
>   received from that satellite. The color shows what data is available
>   for that satellite and how it is currently used by the phone.

Emphasis mine.

Here's the left side of the screen shot I took:

[image: GPS Status & Toolbox showing GPS and GLONASS sats]

The Nexus 7 model would be the European one, if there are any differences.